# Issue with RESTful webservice +JSON+SQL stored procedure project

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest, sql-server-2012

I know for a fact that there is something I miss. My whole project is somewhat copy&paste of various "how to..."s, my knowledge of C# is basic at best and I need to have it working since our standard web service software is RESTful only when sending.

My main problem is that all solutions I've stumbled upon are actually code snippets, which don't work for me - my C# knowledge is basic so I don't understand how it all works, much less troubleshoot it. I'm pretty sure I'm not even capturing the JSON that's being posted with incoming request. But OTOH I may be wrong.

Requirement: something that works off IIS on WS2012R2, can accept JSON files via HTTPPost, dump content into a SQL Server table and return Id for the row that just was created to the sender of the JSON. I will have to build on it to get full-blown web service that sends and receives multiple JSON files containing different data, all have to end up in SQL Server.

What I have:

Class:

```
    namespace NA.Models
{
    public class Note
    {
        public Note() { }

        //public Guid id { get; set; }
        public static string Client { get; set; }
        public static int Case { get; set; }
        public static string Text { get; set; }
        public static int NoteId { get; set; }
        public static string R1 { get; set; }
        public static string R2 { get; set; }
        public static string S1 { get; set; }
        public static DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public static bool Type { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

**Interface**:

```
    namespace NA.Models
{
    interface INoteRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Note> GetAll();
        void Add(Note item);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
namespace NA.Models
{
  class NoteDataRepository : INoteRepository
  {
     public void Add(Note item)
     {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }
        else
        {
            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "BL_IntegrationInsertNote";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.Client.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Case", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.case;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@When", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = item.Date;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ext", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = item.Type;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string id = cmd.Parameters["@return"].Value.ToString();
                string lblMessage = null;
                lblMessage = "Record inserted successfully. ID = " + id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }    
        return item;
    }

    IEnumerable<Note> INoteRepository.GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("getitems");
    }
}
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace NA.Controllers
{
   public class NC : ApiController
   {
      [Route("AddNote")]
      [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostNote(List<Note> item)
    {
        //NoteJson deserializednote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NoteJson>(item);
        //Note notesdata = new Note(item);
        //foreach (deserializednote   
        NotesAccept.Models.INoteRepository Repository = new NotesAccept.Models.NoteDataRepository();
        item = Repository.Add(item);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse < NotesAccept.Models.Note>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

        return response;
    }
   }
}
```

When trying to send test json to the service I get an error in return:

> 500: Internal server error, Value cannot be null at Parameter item

This is posttestserver.com dump of request sent:

```
Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REMOTE_PORT = 56926
REMOTE_ADDR = ip
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = max-age=259200
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = 172.16.3.87
HTTP_VIA = 1.1 koenig.local (squid/3.3.13)
HTTP_EXPECT = 100-continue
CONTENT_LENGTH = 153
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
HTTP_ACCEPT = application/json
CONTENT_TYPE = application/json
UNIQUE_ID = Vri0cUBaMGUAABvGeesAAAAL
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1454945393.4611
REQUEST_TIME = 1454945393

No Post Params.

== Begin post body ==
[{
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Case": 1,
    "Text": "Text",
    "NoteId": 2,
    "R1": "R1",
    "R2": "R2",
    "S1": "S1",
    "Date": "2015-10-26T09:06:46",
    "Type":"1"
}]
== End post body ==

Upload contains PUT data:
[{
    "Client": "Client1",
    "Case": 1,
    "Text": "Text",
    "NoteId": 2,
    "R1": "R1",
    "R2": "R2",
    "S1": "S1",
    "Date": "2015-10-26T09:06:46",
    "Type":"1"
}]
```

The above dump is from POST request which is identical to one I'm sending to my web service, with exception of URL. So can be treated as actual request.
And here is an IIS log:

> Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus
>   sc-win32-status time-taken 2016-02-08 15:49:52 ::1 POST /blz/AddNote -
>   80 - ::1 - - 500 0 0 2937

Comment: 1. remove private Note from Note class
2. update your public static properties in Node to just public
3. use item instead of Node in Add method

Also check this books http://www.asp.net/web-api/books

In case you have some deadlines this book can help ASP.NET Web API 2 Recipes

Comment: @VadimSentyaev Private Note is a suggestion from VB - removed causes error "'Note' does not contain a definition for 'item' and no extension method 'item' accepting a first argument of type 'Note' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) NA" removing statics properties causes the variables used as parameters in stored procedure call to error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property...".

Comment: Just a guess: are u posting the json to your service from a different host? May it be cross origin json problem? 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: @Lorin Actually, I'm posting from different web service located on the same machine, server (both windows and IIS), using setup identical with other, currently working without issue. So barring some bizarre cause that IIS can't handle two web services I can't see problem in POST side. It would be rather in the service that is part of the said project that's the culprit, if at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so there are several things that you need to change to make it working:

1. Add parameterless constructor to Note as it will be needed for deserialization:

   ```
   public Note()
   {
   }
   ```
2. Get rid of "static" in Note's fields:

   public <s>static</s> string Client { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> int Case { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> string Text { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> int NoteId { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> string R1 { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> string R2 { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> string S1 { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> DateTime Date { get; set; }

   public <s>static</s> bool Type { get; set; }
3. Don't send JSON array if you want just 1 object, it won't deserialize. You are expecting single object, not array, so don't send array.
4. You have Type as bool, but you are sending string "1", this will not deserialize to true value as you might expected. Either send true/false (not "true"/"false") or change type of Type to string.
5. Get rid of that private item field, you don't need it:

   <s>private Note item;</s>
6. Get rid of those constructors that you have there

   <s>public Note(string json)</s>

   <s>public Note(Note item)</s>

   Not only that they make no sense and won't work, you don't need them as JSON deserializer will fill the fields for you.

**EDIT:**
For example, you say it does not build because there is no more a constructor with one parameter. Of course it does not build, there is this line

```
Note notesdata = new Note(item);
```

but you do not need that line. What is the idea behind this line? You want an instance of Note class, but you already have it in "item" variable. You do not need to create a second copy of that. So get rid of this too.

Another reason, why it won't compile is that you get rid of those static fields, while you still have this in your Add method:

```
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Note.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@When", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Note.Date;
```

and I am quite sure you do not want that. Instead, you want to use the instance of the object that were sent to you:

```
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@When", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = item.Date;
```

Another thing is that there is usually no reason why would Add method return the object being added to DB. So feel free to change this

```
   public Note Add(Note item)
```

to this

```
   public void Add(Note item)
```

and do not return anything, you do not need it.

I am no expert on SqlConnection and things around it, so that part I do not comment. I use EF in my projects for working with DB. So there might be some problems in that part, but I can't comment on that.

Comment: Thanks for pointers. But the moment I'm removing static from note's field they are no longer available in addNote method. Same with new (Note.item) in controller - after adding parameterless constructor getting error Note.Note() does not contain constructor that takes 1 argument. So solution doesn't build. And last: yes, the json is an array. I may receive more than one note in file. I've just cut it down to one object to keep things simple.

Comment: The PostNote action method must reflect exactly what is being send - it is OK to send array, but in that case, PostNote must accept array (or List) of objects. I understand what you are saying about the other changes I suggested, but the idea was to change other parts of the code too based on that. See my edit for more on that.

Comment: thanks again. :) My comment reflects my knowledge level - minimal. So, any question of the type "what is the idea behind this line" starts with "I don't know - it was in one of the "how to" articles". So your edit is now for me an epiphany at the very least.
As for the DB return - yes, it's needed. For one - if it works its equivalent to success and carries ID of the note for the other system (one that's sending the note) to store it as well.

Comment: OK, so you want Add method to return Note with filled in ID from database. For that, you can just do `item.id = newId` and you do not need to return Note from Add. It is a good thing to know if the call succeeded or not. For that, use bool as a return value, or use exceptions. But avoid combining that. I can see you are throwing ArgumentNullException if item is null. Why not just always return bool - and return false here. Or, why not just use void (i.e. don't return anything) and use exception if DB insert failed. In my style, I avoid exceptions, so I always use bool there.

Comment: Understand, thank you very much. One last issue - where in my solution is the actual json from request body grabbed? I need to have json as an array, I can request change in structure though, so I may have it deserializable if right now it's not. But I have an issue with `List<Note> deserializednote= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Note>>(item);` (item is not a string). How to get past that?

Comment: You don't really need to make the deserialization yourself. Just change `public HttpResponseMessage PostNote(NA.Models.Note item)` to `public HttpResponseMessage PostNote(List<NA.Models.Note> item)`. You can do deserialization yourself, if you want (a good reason might be a performance of the default deserializer), then you would make it just `public HttpResponseMessage PostNote()` and load the data from request manually - `string jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();`

Comment: Thank you. This question is now elevated to "will I have my job tomorrow" (dead serious). And I have an issue: after all changes made as per suggestions the line: `item = Repository.Add(item);` complains that it's not convertible from `List<NA.Models.Note>` to `NA.Models.Note`. Same in `response =` I know it all stems from Array in JSON, but this unfortunately is a requirement. Edited question to show current state of code. Any help, please?

Comment: change to `public HttpResponseMessage PostNote(List<NA.Models.Note> items)` and make `foreach (NA.Models.Note item in items) { ... all processing here ... }`

Comment: Still going nowhere - no idea how to iterate through list of objects and pass each to Add method. every example works on either array or string, which doesn't help, obviously. Also, now it's complaining about not all code paths returning value. Another dead end for me...

Comment: We are well off topic for this issue, how about creating a new SO question for that, share the latest version of your code so that we can look at that. Then send a link to that new SO question here in comments.

Comment: Good idea.
link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293864/how-to-loop-through-list-of-complex-type-objects-and-pass-to-a-method-calling-sq