# How to loop through list of complex type objects and pass to a method calling SQL Stored procedure

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, json, foreach

How to loop through a list of objects in order to pass said object to a method inserting rows in SQL db via stored procedure?

With help [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272514/issue-with-restful-webservice-jsonsql-stored-procedure-project) I got to this point:

```
namespace NA.Controllers
{
   public class NC : ApiController
   {
      [Route("AddNote")]
      [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostNote(List<Note> items)
    {
        //NoteJson deserializednote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NoteJson>(item);
        //Note notesdata = new Note(item);
        NotesAccept.Models.INoteRepository Repository = new NotesAccept.Models.NoteDataRepository();
        foreach (Note item in items)
        {

        item = Repository.Add(item);

        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<List<Note>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
        return response;
    }
   }
}
```

but now I'm stuck as `item=` is now an iteration variable, but I need to pass it to an method:

```
namespace NA.Models
{
  class NoteDataRepository : INoteRepository
  {
     public void Add(Note item)
     {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }
        else
        {
            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "BL_IntegrationInsertNote";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.Client.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Case", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.Case;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@When", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = item.Date;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ext", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = item.Type;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string id = cmd.Parameters["@return"].Value.ToString();
                string lblMessage = null;
                lblMessage = "Record inserted successfully. ID = " + id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }    
        //return item;
    }

    IEnumerable<Note> INoteRepository.GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("getitems");
    }
}
}
```

I'm still green-as-a-grass-newbie to C# so I've no idea how to accomplish that, especially since whole solution is still "copy&Paste" from all over the web, and whole web curiously concentrates on looping through simple types. How to do that with complex type?

As noted in other question, this is a matter of professional life and death (I'm a db dev, not a VS guru, especially not after two days and two nights).

Comment: I don't understand your question, you're not sure how to pass `item` to a function?  Maybe you should show what you have tried and tell us why it didn't work.

Comment: In foreach loop if you use return response, only first value will be processed.

Comment: @CodingGorilla item is an instance of Note() Data class, which is defined so I can deserialize JSON array received via incoming HTTPPost request and store values in it, which said values are parameters for a stored procedure i'm calling in pasted repository. before adding foreach I passed item as described above. Now Item is iteration variable but I still need to pass it (or data it contained before adding foreach()) to Add(Note item).

Comment: @VinayPandey using return to pass back to HTTP request ID of added row. Again: this was before adding foreach(). All you see is code pasted from various "how to...", which i barely understand. How do I pass back OUTPUT from SQL stored proc to response to HTTP request?

Comment: What you are doing is called RBAR "row by agonizing row".  You need to research "set based" approaches to inserting multiple rows.  I get you're a newbie...but trust me, I wish someone had grabbed me when I was a newbie and said "No RBAR".  While I wouldn't user OPENXML , this article discusses the approach . http://tinyurl.com/h2uez8s  Here is a better way then OPENXML  http://tinyurl.com/zxcrsp7

Comment: @CodingGorilla OPENXML is wonderful tool - use it extensively right now as a replacement for another piece of software s**t that could not hack it. I get where you want to point me, but still need to have that solution working - I will look into converting the JSON into XML and let SQL server do bulk of it's job, if that's the way to go in the end. Thanks for reminding me of that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are still forgetting to assign that ID from DB to the item.
2. You also still have

   ```
   return item;
   ```

   in a method that does not return anything (public void Add(Note item)).

   So just delete that return line.
3. And replace

   ```
   item = Repository.Add(item);
   ```

   with just

   ```
   Repository.Add(item);
   ```

Comment: Sorry, as pasted from other question didn't comment out (already done).
Anyway, solution built and published and testing returns:
`"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at NotesAccept.Controllers.NotesController.PostNote(List``1 items)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n (...)`

Comment: So please edit your post to reflect your latest version - including PostNote method changes.

Comment: Which line causes the exception? If you do not know, try to run debugger, or put there some logs to reveal where it crashes.

Comment: You also don't want this part        `var response = Request.CreateResponse < NotesAccept.Models.Note>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

        return response;` to be in the foreach loop, you only want to return the result at the end of the action method.

Comment: Yes, I implemented both your above corrections earlier and didn't update the question. In such a hurry to test and debug the solution...

Trying now - but debug deployed app on remote server takes a while to setup...

Comment: OK, after some debugging and checks it looks like I'm not getting JSON or there's an error parsing JSON. I get : `Procedure or function 'procedure' expects parameter '@Client', which was not supplied`. I've modified controller to try and catch JSON as you suggested in comment to the other question, and debugger shows NULLException here `=response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` what I'm missing here?

Comment: One more thing to get out of the foreach loop is this `        NotesAccept.Models.INoteRepository Repository = new NotesAccept.Models.NoteDataRepository();` that should be called just once. And as for the error you mentioned, I am a bit confused about that. If you replace your response creation line with this: `        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK");` will that error disappear? And do you see the items being added to the database or not? Also, could you add logging to the foreach statement and log to a file what you have in each "item"?

Comment: New Question? ANyway: if I debug api as above I get null exception in this bit: `foreach (Note item in items)`, with pointer underscoring `items`. If I change it to simply capturing json input (the way you suggested elsewhere), I get same null exception in line `=response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`, with pointer pointing to `Result`. That's why I assume the json from request is not passed. I've enabled custom logging on IIS to see if there's anything wrong with request, but can't see anything wrong there.

Comment: I can't really see response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; line in your code ... where is it ?

Comment: ANother question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339306/web-api-debugging-shows-confusing-information

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it as xml and iterate in sql stored procedure and do bulk insert, or you can use table datatype if sql and .net version you are using supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the foreach loop:

```
var tempItem = item;
tempItem = Repository.Add(tempItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Maybe progress: `Can't implicitly convert type void to NA.Models.Note`