# Web API - debugging shows confusing information

Tags: c#, json, debugging, asp.net-web-api, web-config

I've already got help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272514/issue-with-restful-webservice-jsonsql-stored-procedure-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293864/how-to-loop-through-list-of-complex-type-objects-and-pass-to-a-method-calling-sq) with my Web API, but now I think I've arrived to the edge of a Grand Canyon... Fortunately my execution by my boss was postponed, but sentence was not yet commuted. So any suggestions appreciated wholeheartedly, especially since my newbie status in the stuff hasn't yet changed.

So, the code is as shown in second linked question (can post it here, but I think it would be redundant). I've corrected errors with SQL link, so it now doesn't crash when trying to call procedure, set up debug enviro and started testing.

I'm sending a POST request (with JSON in payload) using ARC extension in Chrome while debugging and I have an error message:[image: Error in API with code as intended]

However, after changing code using suggestions from answers and comments to this:

```
namespace NA.Controllers
{
    public class NotesController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("AddNote")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostNote()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
            string jsonData = stream.ReadToEnd();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\BLZ_content.txt", jsonData);
            return response;
        }

    }
}
```

I get a success, correct response and json is being saved to a file. So API in general works fine. This, in turn, means that my code for deserialize json (or just capturing it from body) is not.

Comment: I do not know, how good your programming skills are, but at this point I would go back as much as possible. You receive a null exception because no data received. But at which point? Is there even data arriving at some point in your API, or is the stream even completely non existing? Currently you are searching on the wrong front, have a look at the cables if they are even connected and walk the way the other direction.

Comment: Your Json should be in HttpContext.Current.Request.

Comment: @YoshSynergi Made some changes to code, combining all suggestions here. 'm sure the data hits API (json is saved by said API in a text file). Edited post to reflect the current state of affairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can not read incoming data from the response object you just created. You have to read it from the Request like this:

```
string jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Then you can log it to the file to see if you are getting what you are expecting to get. If you do, you can then deserialize manually jsonData to List like this:

```
List<Note> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Note>>(jsonData);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me... I used @tede24 suggestion from comment above and combined with google search I'm now certain I'm receiving POST messages, as JSON is being saved in a file. So 90% of success. now let's work out on the rest 90% of the problem.

Comment: So what is the problem now? Does the deserialization code using JsonConvert work for you or not? If not, what is a problem.